# What's up with the tag key?

Tags: errors, listings

Subsection 4.18 of the current [`listings` documentation](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (2013/08/26 Version 1.5b) describes a key called `tag`. That key is used in [`lstdrvrs.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx), which is a file that ships with `listings` and takes care of predefining languages. More specifically, the `tag` key is used in the definition of the `HTML` and `XML` languages , as follows:

```
\lst@definelanguage{<languagename>}{
  % ...
  tag=**[s]<>,%
  % ...
}
```

Why, then, can't I use the `tag` key in the definition of a custom language? For instance, the code below throws the following error:

```
!Package keyval Error: tag undefined.
```

My TeX distribution is up-to-date. I don't understand...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}%
{%
    tag=**[s]<>,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=mylang]
<b>foobar</b>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation neglects to mention that the `tag` key is defined (in `lstmisc.sty`) only within the `html` "aspect" (not language). Loading this aspect with

```
\lstloadaspects{html}
```

(or as package option) will place the `tag` key at your disposal. You could also load it in the last optional argument of `\lstdefinelanguage`:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{tag=**[s]<>}[html]
```