# Highlight code with squared brackets

Tags: listings, highlighting, code

I want to show some .ini file in my work. The ini file works with squared brackets. I try to use \lstdefinelanguage but I can't handle it. That is what I try before and in my understanding it should work but it doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{Ini}
{
        tag=[s][],
        tagstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        usekeywordsintag=true
}

\lstset{
    language=Ini
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
[test]
a=15
b=4
[test1]
c=25
d=5
[test2]
e=50
f=5
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

That is how it should look:

[image]

Highlight the background behind the keywords wouldn't be that necessary but a nice gimmick.

An problem what I don't understand is how should Latex handle this case:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Ini]
[test]
a=1
\end{lstlisting}
```

How can latex difference between the property and the content?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of just a snippet of code, could you edit your question to include a complete (yet minimal) example, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: [Related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158609/7674)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `listings` documentation (page 44) mentions that the key tag is language specific (to HTML), so you need to make it available to your language

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{Ini}
{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  tag=[s]{[]},
  tagstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  usekeywordsintag=true
}[html]

\lstset{
    language=Ini
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
[test]
a=15
b=4
[test1]
c=25
d=5
[test2]
e=50
f=5
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding your last question,"how should LaTeX handle this case"

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Ini]
[test]
a=1
\end{lstlisting}
```

`lstlisting` postpones the processing for verbatim material until having read the optional argument for `lstlisting`.

Comment: Is there a way to have the equal sign highlighted in red?